# How the function is working in the below code

Tags: javascript

I want to ask how the moveRight() function is working. I am aware of that when the "Click me " button is clicked then the moveRight() function is called so basically the code should call the moveright() function and return to the html after that function is executed , so there is no way of executing init() function. How the whole thing is working.

JavaScript Animation

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
     <!--
        var imgObj = null;

        function init() {
           imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
           imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        }

        function moveRight() {
           imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
        }

        window.onload = init;
     //-->
  </script>
```

```
  <form>
     <img id = "myImage" src = "/images/html.gif" />
     <p>Click button below to move the image to right</p>
     <input type = "button" value = "Click Me" onclick = "moveRight();" />
  </form>
```

Comment: You are also calling init onload ? isn't it ?

Comment: "*so there is no way of executing init()*" but what about `window.onload = init;`?

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of what window.onload is.

Comment: Although this is a rather simple question, Stack Overflow would not be the place to ask how functional code is working. I would suggest that you read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you declare an `init` function, which sets up some styles on your image.

Secondly, you declare a `moveRight` function, which adds `10px` to the `left` style property of the image and thereby moving the image to the right.

Then you make the script call the `init` function when the document loads.

Lastly, in your `<input type="button" ... />` you call the `moveRight` function when it is clicked.

Comment: @Techie Did my answer help you?

Comment: When the function moveRight() is called , then imgObj is undefined no?
What is the order of execution of the functions, moveRight() then init() or init then moveRIght() ?

Comment: `init` then `moveRight`, because `init` is called when the document loads, and `moveRight` is first called when you click the button